# Stacking order of product page that utilizes jQZoom

Tags: css, z-index, jqzoom

I have a [product page](https://www.williambandfriends.com/shop/activewear-product/) that uses jQZoom, but I can't get the stacking order to show correctly (and jQZoom isn't showing the full-size image on hover, but that's for another post). The product image div is currently blocking the product details to the right, preventing the user from clicking "Add to Cart" or any of the dropdowns.

I've tried seemingly every combination of CSS to fix the issue, but I can't figure it out. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem div/style. It was a matter of a conflicting `overflow` style. I changed the containing div to `overflow: visible` and the zoom box now shows in the proper stacking order on hover, and the product buttons are still clickable, etc.